# excercise 3.3 in accelerated c++

Tags: c++

I'm working through the book Accelerated c++ and solving currently exercise 3.3, which says:

> Write a program to count how many times each distinct word appears in its input.

My solution to this problem is the following code:

```
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
  std::cout << "please enter as many words as wanted" << std::endl;
  std::vector<std::string> s;
  std::string tempstring; 

  while(std::cin >> tempstring){
    s.push_back(tempstring);
    }

  std::vector<std::string> unique;
  std::vector<int> count;

  std::vector<std::string> copy = s;

  while(copy.size()>0){
    std::string search = copy[0];
    int temp = 1;
    unique.push_back(search);
    for(int i = 1;i < copy.size();++i){
      if(copy[i]==search){
    ++temp;
    copy.erase(copy.begin()+i);
      }
    }
    count.push_back(temp);
    copy.erase(copy.begin());
  }

  for(int i = 0;i<unique.size();++i){
    std::cout << unique[i] << " occurs "  << count[i] << " times" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If I use the input `Jo Hi Hi Jo Jo Jo me done` I get the following output:

```
thinkstation:~c++/accelerated_code/exercises/chapter_3$ ./ex3_3 
please enter as many words as wanted
Jo Hi Hi Jo Jo Jo me done
Jo occurs 3 times
Hi occurs 2 times
Jo occurs 1 times
me occurs 1 times
done occurs 1 times
```

Why does it not delete all `Jo`? If I just run

```
thinkstation:~c++/accelerated_code/exercises/chapter_3$ ./ex3_3 
please enter as many words as wanted
Jo Jo Hi
Jo occurs 2 times
Hi occurs 1 times
```

it works fine.

Comment: You are counting consecutive occurrences of the same word.

Comment: Using a [better data structure](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) make it *much* easier.

Comment: @juanchopanza thx for the hint! I was able to fix it :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Up to chapter 3 map was not covered. However, I will have a look at it. thx!

Comment: @juanchopanza although his output happens to say Jo occurs 1 and Jo occurs 3 times, it's only coincidence that that matches up with the consecutive sequences. His error is not that he's counting consecutive occurrences of the same word.

Comment: Congratulations on the sensible choice of the textbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code to remove duplicates:

```
for(int i = 1;i < copy.size();++i){
  if(copy[i]==search){
    ++temp;
    copy.erase(copy.begin()+i);
  }
}
```

Note that when you do remove a word, and thus slide all following words down one index, you still increment `i`, thus the duplicate check skips the next word.

---

The standard library includes several algorithms that can be used to implement a solution. You could use `std::remove` to replace your code for checking for and counting duplicates:

```
while(copy.size()>0){
  std::string search = copy[0];

  auto new_end = std::remove(copy.begin(), copy.end(), search);
  int temp = copy.end() - new_end;
  copy.erase(new_end, copy.end());

  count.push_back(temp);
  unique.push_back(search);
}
```

Some other algorithms that could be helpful for various solutions: `std::sort`, `std::unique`, and `std::count`, and `std::upper_bound`.

Comment: using your code I get an compiler error: ex3_3.cpp:26:10: error: ‘new_end’ does not name a type. What is the reason for that? (gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5))

Comment: @user8 Replace `auto new_end` with `std::vector<std::string>::iterator new_end`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious thanks, it works now perfectly. what was the issue?

Comment: @user8 `auto` provides automatic type deduction in C++11 and pre-C++1 it's always an integer type.